# How to use getStoredState properly in redux-persist

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I'm not sure if I am using the `getStoredState` from redux-persist library correctly. I'd like to use the store that has been persisted as the default redux store.

config/store.js

```
async function getState() {
  const storedState = await getStoredState({ storage: AsyncStorage });

  const store = createStore(reducers, storedState, compose(
    applyMiddleware(logger),
    autoRehydrate()
  ));
  persistStore(store, {storage: AsyncStorage);
}

export default getState();
```

App.js

```
import store from 'config/store';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

export default () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    //
  </Provider>
)
```

This produces the following warnings:

```
Warning: Failed child context type: The child context `store.subscribe` is marked as required in `Provider`, but its value is `undefined`.

Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `store.subscribe` is marked as required in `Provider`, but its value is `undefined`
```

Any ideas what is causing these warnings? I have a feeling I've done something wrong in store.js

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you are trying to instantiate the Provider your store variable is still pending: the getStoreState method returns a Promise, so you have to wait until it completes to use the store.

This example shows a sample implementation:

```
import {getStoredState, createPersistor} from 'redux-persist'

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.store = null
    this.persistor = null
  }

  componentWillMount(){
    const persistConfig = {storage: AsyncStorage}
    getStoredState(persistConfig, (err, restoredState) => {
      this.store = createStore(
        reducers,
        restoredState,
        compose(
          applyMiddleware(logger,)
        )
      )
      this.persistor = createPersistor(this.store, persistConfig)
      // Now that we have the store setted, reload the component
      this.forceUpdate()
    })
   }

  render() {
    if (!this.store) {
      // Loading screen
      return <Text>Loading</Text>
    } else {
      return (
          <Provider store={this.store}>
            <Router />
          </Provider>
      )
    }

  }
}
```

Any improvements tips are welcome.